# Does $v_n\to v$ a.e. $\implies$ $|v_n(x)|^{p-2} v_n(x) \to |v(x)|^{p-2} v(x)$ a.e.?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let $\Omega$ be an open bounded domain $p\in (1, \infty)$ and let $(v_n)_n \subset C^\infty_0(\Omega)$ be a sequence of functions such that $v_n\to v$ a.e. in $\Omega$.

It is possible to conclude that
$$|v_n(x)|^{p-2} v_n(x) \to |v(x)|^{p-2} v(x) \text{ a.e. in } \Omega?$$

I do not know how to argue about the term to the $(p-2)$-power.

Anyone could help with that?

Comment: Let $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function and $v_n\rightarrow v$ a.e. then $f(v_n) \rightarrow f(v)$ a.e.. This is because there exists a set $F\subseteq \Omega$ such that $\Omega\setminus F$ is a null set and $v_n(x) \rightarrow v(x)$ for all $x\in F$. In particular, we have (by continuity) $f(v_n(x)) \rightarrow f(v(x))$ for all $x\in F$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. For $p\geq 2$ use the fact that $f(p_n(x))\to f(p(x))$ a.e. for any continuous function $f$.

For $1<p<2$ consider points $x$ with $v(x)=0$ and points $x$ with $v (x) \neq 0$ sepately. Use the fact that $|t|^{p-2}t \to 0$ as $t \to 0$.